# How to Connect Function to PyQT5 GUI in Python

Tags: function, user-interface, pyqt5

```
import sys
from os import path

import cv2
import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui

import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import image_to_string
from gtts import gTTS
import os


pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"


tessdata_dir_config = r'--tessdata-dir "C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata"'



class RecordVideo(QtCore.QObject):
    image_data = QtCore.pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        self.timer = QtCore.QBasicTimer()

    def start_recording(self):
        self.timer.start(0, self)

    
    def timerEvent(self, event):
        if (event.timerId() != self.timer.timerId()):
            return

        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            self.image_data.emit(data)
    def framesave(self):
        
        read, data = self.camera.read()
        if read:
            cv2.imwrite('a.png',data)
            img=Image.fromarray(data)
            img.load()
            
            text=pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='spa', config=tessdata_dir_config)
        


class FaceDetectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()
        self._red = (0, 0, 255)
        self._width = 2
        self._min_size = (30, 30)


    def image_data_slot(self, image_data):


        
        self.image = self.get_qimage(image_data)
        if self.image.size() != self.size():
            self.setFixedSize(self.image.size())

        self.update()
    
        
        
    def get_qimage(self, image: np.ndarray):
        height, width, colors = image.shape
        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        QImage = QtGui.QImage

        image = QImage(image.data,
                       width,
                       height,
                       bytesPerLine,
                       QImage.Format_RGB888)

        image = image.rgbSwapped()
        return image

def static_ROI(self, cropped:np.ndarray):
    # height, width = image.shape[:2]
    #
    # top_left_x = int(width / 3)
    # top_left_y = int((height / 2) + (height / 4))
    # bottom_right_x = int((width / 3) * 2)
    # bottom_right_y = int((height / 2) - (height / 4))
    #
    # cv2.rectangle(image, (top_left_x, top_left_y), (bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y), 255, 3)
    #
    # image = image[bottom_right_y:top_left_y, top_left_x:bottom_right_x]

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        self.image = QtGui.QImage()


class MainWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.face_detection_widget = FaceDetectionWidget()

        # TODO: set video port
        self.record_video = RecordVideo()

        image_data_slot = self.face_detection_widget.image_data_slot
        self.record_video.image_data.connect(image_data_slot)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.face_detection_widget)
        self.run_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Start')
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button)

        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.record_video.start_recording)

        self.screenshot = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Snap Shot')
        layout.addWidget(self.screenshot)

        self.screenshot.clicked.connect(self.record_video.framesave)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    main_widget = MainWidget()
    main_window.setCentralWidget(main_widget)
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Above is the code which makes character recognition on live Camera View. I would like to add static ROI to limit interested area  and below code does this :

```
height, width = frame.shape[:2]

            # Define ROI Box Dimensions
            top_left_x = int(width / 3)
            top_left_y = int((height / 2) + (height / 4))
            bottom_right_x = int((width / 3) * 2)
            bottom_right_y = int((height / 2) - (height / 4))

            # Draw rectangular window for our region of interest
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (top_left_x, top_left_y), (bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y), 255, 3)

            # Crop window of observation we defined above
            cropped = frame[bottom_right_y:top_left_y, top_left_x:bottom_right_x]
```

How could I make the GUI connection for this function below?

What I have tried is to call this function under the FaceDetectionWidget classbut it didn't work. What I want to have is:

[image: LiveView with ROI]

I wonder in which class should I create this function and how to call it.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), even if it doesn't work as expected. Show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have tried to create function from the below code as Static_ROI under record_video class  and called it with  self.record_video.Static_ROI() and didn't work. Then I tried another variations such as adding the function under face_detection and call it from __init__. Because there are needed to work both live video and ROI square it is provided complexity in my mind. I am trying to learn it and this would be great training for me.

Comment: I don't understand. You said you created a `Static_ROI` function (btw, where is it?), and didn't work: *what* didn't work? Anyway, if you want to draw *on* the image, you should do it in the `timerEvent` *before* emitting the signal. Besides that, should the ROI be directly drawn on the image? Can't you draw it in the paintEvent?

Comment: oh sorry I didn't add my updates while asking. now I updated the question. But I think there is something needeed to be added on MainWidget. I need help on it because I have no idea what I should add there.

Comment: Please answer all questions: has the ROI to be drawn directly on the image? In that case, have you tried to draw directly on the image before emitting the signal? If not, can't you just draw a rectangle in the paintEvent?

Comment: Yes I want it to be created on live view directly opening the live so i will move the camera to record interested area in that region. There is another button to capture the characters in that area. So the question is how I could create the function. Face_detection_widget.static_ROI() didn’t worked. Should I call it with image or image_frame_data. These ones provided error. What should I use to call it correctly?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Should the ROI be drawn directly on the image (as in "the image contents are actually modified") or can it be simply shown in the interface?

Comment: No it should not but my first aim is functionality of the process. But i don’t prefer modifying. My thought was to create a mask and process on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make it simpler and draw the ROI in the paintEvent of the widget.

```
class FaceDetectionWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    drawROI = True
    # ...
    def setDrawROI(self, draw):
        self.drawROI = draw
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawImage(0, 0, self.image)
        if not self.drawROI:
            return
        width = self.image.width()
        height = self.image.height()
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.red, 2))
        painter.drawRect(width / 3, height / 4, width / 3, height / 2)
```

You can then enable/disable the ROI by using `setDrawROI(True/False)`.

Comment: You're welcome! Remember that if an answer solved your issue you might want to set it as accepted by clicking on the check mark on the left of it.